# Logging only transferred files with rsync

Tags: rsync

I've created a backup script with rsync and I have it running every 10 minutes. I am copying files from HFS to Fat32. I have it logging using `--progress` but to make reading the log easier I only want to include files that are transferred. I.e. at the end of a run I would like to see something in the log like:

```
Started transfer at 2012-07-31 11:03:45

/some/file/that/was/changed.txt
/another/file/that/was/added.jpg

Number of files: 35184
Number of files transferred: 2
```

I can't find anything after a bit of googling. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `--stats` instead of `--progress`?

Comment: Yeah but it doesn't state which files were transferred.

Comment: I've noticed that the reason it was listing everything is because I was using the -a flag. I changed it to -tr because I'm rsyncing to fat32 and the other options of -a don't really matter. It seems to only print the progress of transferred files now rather than all of them. I don't know why this works but I suspect that it's because fat32 can't store some aspect of the file (like it does with timestamps) and rsync thinks it needs to be updated a second time when it looks like the file is different.

Comment: @jeanaux Please add more information to your question, such as a simple log, and the fact that your target filesystem is fat32 (using a non-native filesystem is an important piece of information). Then answer your question, ideally mentioning which particular aspect was causing the problem if you can find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out in the end. I noticed that the reason it was listing everything was because I was using the -a flag.

I'm syncing to fat32 so something about the -a flag was causing it to try to sync all the files every time.

I changed the flags to -tr and that solved the problem. I don't know what it was about the -a flag that was causing it but I know that fat32 isn't as detailed as other files systems and file comparisons don't always work properly between filesystems as a result.

Comment: `-a` equals `-rlptgoD`. In fat32, permissions (`-p`), owner (`-o`) and group (`-g`) probably won't match (they're fixed as mount options for fat32), so rsync will try to update them (as you told it), but will fail everytime.