# Exclude from rsync log file or output non-updated files

Tags: grep, rsync, logs, msys

For `rsync`s that involve a large number of potentially transferred files, I mean to have a "clean" log, with only what was transferred.

I worked with `stdout`, since:

1. I did not know how to configure the log output (if that is even possible).
2. I also want this to work with `--dry-run` (which forced me to work with something like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/230720/137608), since).
3. I mean to write scripts useful for transferring Linux-Linux, and Linux-msys2 (and viceversa) at least. Here, options for permissions (`-p`), owner (`-o`) and group (`-g`) may complicate things.

I combined command

```
rsync --recursive --perms --group --owner --times --one-file-system --sparse --stats --progress --update --out-format='%t %p %i %n %M %l' --delete --dry-run --include="*" --exclude="*" --log-file=rsync.log ./ ../trg
```

with

```
... | grep -E -v ' \.[fdLDS][\.c][\.s][\.t][\.p][\.o][\.g][\.u][\.a][\.x]'
```

following the description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12037164/2707864).
The first dot matches any item that is not being updated.
The second character matches any item type.
The remaining characters match any condition on the attributes (change/no change)
Flag `-v` reverts matching. This presumably matches any item that is being updated, and only that. Items not updated, but with changed timestamp, would not be matched.

I finally combine this with `tee`, as in

```
rsync --recursive --perms --group --owner --times --one-file-system --sparse --stats --progress --update --out-format='%t %p %i %n %M %l' --delete --dry-run --include="*" --exclude="*" --log-file=rsync.log ./ ../trg | grep -E -v ' \.[fdLDS][\.c][\.s][\.t][\.p][\.o][\.g][\.u][\.a][\.x]' | tee rsync.2.log
```

which produces the `rsync` log file `rsync.log`, and my "custom" log file `rsync.2.log`.

Even if it seems to work, the 3 "weak" points of my approach are the following:

1. I am not sure there are cases I am missing, where this approach might fail (by "excessive" reporting or filtering files).
2. I would like to handle this natively via `rsync` itself. Even better, getting the output in the `rsync` log file (not only its output), rather than using the brute force `grep` approach.
   Note that using `--itemize-changes` I get in stdout some files with e.g. status `.f...p.....`, which should be filtered (as they are not updated, first character is a dot).
3. Using `grep` I cannot see the partial progress. I am not sure if for very large output this can be a major problem.

**Related**:

1. [how to make rsync to log deleted files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203848/how-to-make-rsync-to-log-deleted-files)
2. [How to make rsync display only files being copied, not all the folders which are scanned?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/508331/how-to-make-rsync-display-only-files-being-copied-not-all-the-folders-which-are)
3. [Logging only transferred files with rsync](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44372/logging-only-transferred-files-with-rsync)
4. https://superuser.com/questions/1002074/linux-command-line-to-create-a-log-file-for-rsync
5. https://serverfault.com/questions/401210/rsync-report-only-uploaded-files

**Note**:
The subtleties in this question (see also answer) make it slightly different from other similar questions posted/linked.
Whether this warrants a separate question is a blurred line, and subjective.
I personally find it useful to leave it as it is now.

Comment: Can I just check, you want to list just the files (and directories, presumably) that were transferred or updated?

Comment: @roaima - Yes. I am not sure if with the description "updated" there is still some ambiguity. rsync documentation uses that terminology, so I guess there should be none. And if there is some, I am eager to understand it to properly select my output.

Comment: @roaima - Note: I have slightly edited the bottom of the OP.

Comment: Related (from a sister site) - [How to output a list of changed files from rsync?](https://serverfault.com/q/618735/267016)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [See only changes when running rsync](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/341413/see-only-changes-when-running-rsync)

Comment: @roaima - Interesting links. I will check if they perform as intended. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had 3 requirements:

1. Configure log output. For this, `--itemize-changes`, as in links I had posted, and others added by @roaima, works well.
2. Work with `--dry-run`. For this, `--itemize-changes` is still useful to produce the intended output, albeit only in stdout, and not in the log file. There seems to be no alternative.
3. Work with various combinations of OS (src/trg). Linux-Linux, and Linux-msys2 (and viceversa), at least. In the case of Msys2, being NTFS, permissions can't match those of an ext4. So already `rsync`ed files will keep showing, producing very long lists. In this case, `--perms` should be removed. Note that this would not replicate read-only <-> read-write permission changes either; I don't have a neat solution for all cases so far. Other than this, `--itemize-changes` is still useful in this case.